# Set file formatting type to UTF-8 project (or solution) wide in a C# project?

Tags: visual-studio, utf-8, .net-6.0

My team is working on a relatively big Solution in .NET 6.0 (50+ projects), we have people working with Ubuntu, MacOS and Windows. Windows users are using either Visual Studio or Rider, the rest are using VSCode or Rider. The problem is that many of the German-specific characters gets messed up whenever the code moves from an OS to another. Is there a way to force my .NET projects or solution to save files only in UTF-8 to avoid these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [.editorconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022) file in the root folder of the solution and add [`charset`](https://editorconfig.org/#supported-properties) property to it:

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
```